# AES 256bit encryption with Bouncy Castle: Unlimited Strength Policy still required?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I want to use AES 256bit encryption with [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) and I'm wondering if the "[Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)" are still required despite BC because I'm receiving a `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size` exception for the following code:

```
public class AES256 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        final KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(256); // doesn't work for 192, too

        final byte[] encoded = keyGen.generateKey().getEncoded();

        final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
        final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
        // Please ignore static IV for this example
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15});

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv); // throws java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to use 256bit keys without the Unlimited Strength Policy files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First question in the bouncycastle [FAQ](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions).

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a FAQ under documentation of the Bouncy Castle website but not under Wiki. So BC provides better (AES) encryption algorithm but does not circumvent the Unlimited Strength Policy issue. I was hoping I could prevent this installation step for the users of the application.

Comment: seriously? I still have to install the java unlimited strengh policy add on..? isn't there a way (library) to do it without?