# Decrypting data in Java from PHP mcrypt using Rijndael_256(AES)

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

For a few days i have been trying to get the encrypted data from a PHP service to my android application. I want to use Rijndael 256 bit encryption.

Encrypting and decrypting a string in PHP works fine.
What i do is i send the data from php to android in the 
following structure = (initialization vector + hash(md5) + encrypted data).

In Java i split the received string in 3 compartments.

But what i get in java is a error message telling: IV must be 16 bytes long.
I checked all over the internet trying to find a solution to this problem.
Some suggested not using mcrypt in php while others said to use a 128 algorithm variant. Using 128 bit in PHP breaks the encryption.

Below i have 2 examples to perhaps clarify the problem further.

I appreciate your help.

PHP CODE encryption / decryption:

```
   function encrypt_data($data,$privk)
{
// Random number for feeding into AES encyption algorithm
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
// Check if decrypted properly
$hash = md5($data);
// Encrypt the data using the privk and the iv
$encrypted = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $privk, trim($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
$encode = base64_encode($encrypted);

$base64_iv = base64_encode($iv);

return $base64_iv.$hash.'='.$encode;
}
function decrypt_data($data,$privk)
{
// Split data into 3 variables: iv,hash,encdata
$arr = explode('=',$data,3);    
$iv  = base64_decode($arr[0]);
$hash = $arr[1];
$encdata = base64_decode($arr[2]);
// Decrypt using the 3 variables
$decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $privk, trim($encdata), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

// Check integrity of decrypted data
$hdec = md5($decrypted);

if ($hdec == $hash)
{
    return $decrypted;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

JAVA decryption:

```
    public String decryptJson(String data)
{
    String[] split= data.trim().split("=");

    byte[] iv = Base64.decode(split[0],3);      
    String hash = split[1];
    byte[] encd = Base64.decode(split[2],0);

    String skey  = "secretkeyfromdatabase";
    byte[] skeyb = skey.getBytes();

            try
            {                   
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            SecretKeySpec skeyspec = new SecretKeySpec(skeyb,"AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,skeyspec,ivspec);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encd);

            return original.toString();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR! | "+ex+"IV:"+iv;
            }
}
```

Comment: After seeing the error message telling "IV must be 16 bytes long" you should have checked what is the length of your `byte[] iv` and why it is not 16 bytes.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I see it is 32 bytes in length. Is there a way so that it can accept a 32 byte IV?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**"I see it is 32 bytes in length. Is there a way so that it can accept a 32 byte IV?"**

No. The underlying problem is that "Rijndael_256" in mcrypt is a Rijndael variant that uses 256 bit blocksize instead of 128 bit blocksize that is used in all AES versions. You will have difficulties to find any implementation of "Rijndeal_256" other than the mcrypt library. (See [How can I do this same encrypt/decrypt PHP function on iOS with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089465/how-can-i-do-this-same-encrypt-decrypt-php-function-on-ios-with-objective-c))

**Edit**: Bouncy Castle actually supports Rijndeal_256 via `RijndaelEngine`: [Encryption in Android equivalent to php's MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101545/encryption-in-android-equivalent-to-phps-mcrypt-rijndael-256/18114859#18114859)

**"Some suggested not using mcrypt in php while others said to use a 128 algorithm variant."**

Both suggestions are correct. mcrypt is a horrible library, but if you have to you can get something running with "Rijndael_128", which *is* identical to AES128.

**Some remarks on your code**: You hash the verbatim data `md5($data)` but encrypt a trimmed plaintext `trim($data)`. You use the default zero padding of mcrypt but specify PKCS5Padding in Java, this wont't work. As you use CBC but no authentication after encryption and before decryption you are likely prone to *padding oracle attacks*.

**"Yeah well im new in using cryptography." - Alternatives:**

Given your current level of cryptography expertise you should avoid implementing any cryptography at all. Instead use high level libraries and protocols. Which one to use greatly depends on your use case. For example if the PHP code runs on a trusted server and the Java code on the client side you can connect to the server via SSL/TLS (most likely using *https*). The TLS connection will authenticate the server to the client and you can use [basic http authentcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to authenticate the client to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of your problems is that JCE does not support AES 256 bits (maximum 128 if you won't change the JCE policy files). Either use 128 bit encryption for PHP or...

As you can see in the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#importlimits) "If stronger algorithms are needed (for example, AES with 256-bit keys), the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files must be obtained and installed in the JDK/JRE."

It is the user's responsibility to verify that this action is permissible under local regulations.

Comment: hmm ok thanks for clarifying! It wasn't clear to me java doesn't support the stronger algorithms at all. I did find a java library called: Bouncycastle Rijndaelengine. I shall try that one out

Comment: Using BC will not solve your problem, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895031/aes-256bit-encryption-with-bouncy-castle-unlimited-strength-policy-still-requir

Comment: Two things: 1. AES256 isn't actually stronger than AES128, [Schneier advises the use of AES128 instead](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html); 2. "Rijndael_256" used in mcrypt is not AES256, but a variant with 256 bit block size that is supported by basically no one. (@Menno)

Comment: Actually, you can use Bouncy to circumvent, but you need to use the Bouncy Castle "lightweight" API directly. This may or may not be useful for your scenario.

Comment: Yeah well im new in using cryptography. I think i then shall just revert back to 128 bit AES that seems to be the most reasonable choice. Thank you very much !