# replace JCE with Bouncycastle jar

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I have to get rid of JCE jars and should be replaced with bouncy castle jar for AES encryption and decryption.

I am getting invalid key size exception when i replace JCE policy jars with BC jars for AES 256 algorithm. But it works well with key size 128.

How can i make use of BC jars in case of AES 256 algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more detail. How did you replace the `jce.jar` and why exactly? Bouncy has a Java crypto implementation to add/replace for Java, but that's only for Java 1.2, 1.3 - old versions of Java.

Comment: We are upgrading java version from java 6 to java 7 in our applications.   java installation is automated through scripting by specifying the jdk version number.In that we had to replace the policy JCE jars specific to Java 7 instead java6.  So What we thought each time during upgrade, we need not replace JCE jars if we give bouncy castle jars in classpath would be sufficient for AES 256 encryption.

Comment: The restriction is in the `Cipher` class. While I'm not certain you *cannot* do what you are trying to do, I don't think you are on the right path.

Comment: Can we perform AES 256 encryption by just using BC jars alone, without overwriting JCE policy jars in jdk lib folder.   I tried following the link, but wiki page itself is down from BC website. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895031/aes-256bit-encryption-with-bouncy-castle-unlimited-strength-policy-still-requir?rq=1

Comment: Yes, you can, but you cannot use `Cipher` or any classes that rely on it. Instead you can use the "lightweight API", i.e. directly calling the Bouncy Castle classes like `BufferedBlockCipher` and related. This will of course also disallow using AES in a higher level protocol that requires `Cipher`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. But AES encryption still work well for 128 bit with BC jars.

Comment: Of course, because `Cipher` only checks for higher bitsizes...

Comment: can i use aes/cbc/pkcs5padding cipher algorithm with bouncycastle api without using overridden poilicy jars?

Comment: Yes, but only those classes in `org.bouncycastle`. There are no checks, the JRE does not detect cryptographic algorithms or anything (that would be quite an accomplishment if it could :P), for the runtime they are just ordinary classes. You cannot use those classes for protocols *build on top of* JCE functionality of course.

Comment: We have encrypted messages in production without BC jars. I am having a requirement to replace the JCE with BC jars. From your responses i understood that i can use only light weight API of BC to have 256 AES encryption without policy jars. However, I have to implement same algorithm only,then only the encrypted messages that are available in production will be decrypted accordingly. Sorry to trouble you more.

Comment: It's a bit of a rewrite, but the algorithms are basically the same. So this is certainly a route you can take for decrypting a proprietary message format. Normally you should of course just use the unlimited crypto files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer assumes that it is not possible to install the [unlimited strength jurisdictional cryptography files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) using the scripting mentioned.**

---

The key size restraint of `Cipher` is in the `Cipher` class itself. It is not (easily) possible to bypass it.

Instead you could use the Bouncy Castle lightweight API. The lightweight API is lightweight for the amount of classes are required for the API implementation itself, not so much for you though.

For example (AES CBC with PKCS#7 (PKCS#5 compatible) padding:

```
public class BouncyLightWeightCipherExample {

    private static final boolean FOR_DECRYPTION = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, Exception {
        final byte[] keyData = new byte[256 / Byte.SIZE];
        final byte[] ivData = new byte[16];
        final byte[] testData = "owlstead".getBytes(UTF_8);

        // JCE creation
        final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // initialization
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(ivData));

        // and encryption
        final byte[] ciphertext = c.doFinal(testData);

        // Bouncy Castle creation
        final BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESFastEngine();
        final CBCBlockCipher withModeOfOperation = new CBCBlockCipher(blockCipher);
        final PaddedBufferedBlockCipher withPadding = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(withModeOfOperation);

        // initialization
        final ParametersWithIV keyAndIV = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(keyData), ivData);
        withPadding.init(FOR_DECRYPTION, keyAndIV);

        // and decryption
        int plaintextSize = withPadding.processBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length, ciphertext, 0);
        plaintextSize += withPadding.doFinal(ciphertext, plaintextSize);
        final byte[] plaintext = Arrays.copyOf(ciphertext, plaintextSize);

        // there we are
        System.out.println(new String(plaintext, UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Comment: As usual this an excellent and thorough answer. However, judging from the comments and his succeeding questions I'm not sure the OP understands that he needs to rewrite his code using the example from `// Bouncy Castle creation` and below and *must* throw away the code use JCE classes.

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt using AES 256, you have to use the  ‘Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files’. There are 2 jars, local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar.

You can get these files from oracle website.

Once you have these jars, replace the "your_java_installation_directory/jre/lib/security" jars with these.