# AES 256 encryption with Bouncy Castle jars light weight API without policy jars

Tags: encryption, aes, bouncycastle

In our application We have already implemented AES 256 encryption. We wanted to replace unlimited policy jars with Bouncy Castle jars.

Can i use the same below algorithms that was already implemented using Bouncy castle's light weight API for AES 256 encryption without using overridden policy jars.

Comment: The answer would be yes. Please try and come back if you run into problems (with the Bouncy PBKDF2 implementation, I already answered your AES 256 decryption [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25249177/589259)

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace JCE with Bouncycastle jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208799/replace-jce-with-bouncycastle-jar)