# Replace default TLS stack for OpenSSL in Windows

Tags: ssl, .net-core, openssl, tls1.2

Recently, we have encountered a problem while installing one of our applications for a customer. During installation the application needs to perform some requests to our cloud service and we realised it could not establish HTTPS connection: the very TLS handshake failed. After researching a bit we found the server was a Windows Server 2008 which does not support TLS v1.2, which is the minimum required to connect to our servers. There are some workarounds ([this one](https://knowledge.digicert.com/quovadis/ssl-certificates/ssl-general-topics/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.html), for instance) but none of them worked. In addition, we cannot install any update to that windows due to customer policies.

While looking for a solution, using wireshark, we noticed that our program tried to connect using TLS v1.2 and failed, but Chrome browser was able to connect to the same cloud server using TLS v1.3, which is not even supported in Windows Server 2008. From that we deduced that Chrome is likely using its own TLS stack to establish the connection.

I am wondering that if Chrome is doing that, we should also be able to do the same. The application is developed in .Net Core and I have googled a lot looking for information on how to do this, and I've found lots of information on how to configure TLS certificates in .Net Core, but none on replacing the TLS stack with, say, OpenSSL or others. I do know this [is possible in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208799/replace-jce-with-bouncycastle-jar), so **is  it possible to replace the TLS stack in .Net core?**

Comment: Possible alternative: could you enable 1.1 on a special server to be used only by these backward customers, restricted by IPaddr and/or time and maybe login/user if available e.g. they must notify you 'we need low-quality connections from 192.168.0.1 for the next 2 hours' and you enable only that? Or if you have someone onsite they make (and endorse) the request?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yeah, we thought of that but our feeling but the user has dynamic IP, what makes this solution more difficult to operate. In addition, out feeling is that we are going to find more "legacy" customers like this, and we are looking for a more definitive solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core itself doesn't let you plug in your own crypto stack.

You pointed to Bouncy Castle as an example of Java letting you use an alternate crypto stack; there's [a port of Bouncy Castle to C#/.NET as well](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).

Their source code has a test case that demonstrates how to write a TLS client using Bouncy Castle:

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/test/src/crypto/tls/test/TlsClientTest.cs

Comment: This provides us with a way to establish TLS connections using another stack, which is good. In addition, we would need to build our own HTTPS methods on top of this. Do you know if it is possible to override in some way `System.Net.HttpClient` so that we do not need to chanage all our code? I was taking a look at [its code ](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs) but I am not sure I can replace the way the connection is established.

Comment: Following my last comment, it is possible to "override" the internals of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` passing to its constructor your own instance of a [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=net-5.0). Inside this handler the "only" thing you need to do is to implement the `SendAsync` method so that it returns a proper `HttpResponseMessage`. This can be achieved under the hood using libcurl or any of its wrappers, which has its own crypto (OpenSSL), solving the problem, with minimal changes to preexisting code.